# Need An Explanation of Steps to Rotate AV Camera

Tags: swift, ios8, avfoundation

So I am having an issue with rotations. I have an AV Camera set up to display in a view controller. Now I know there are a lot of components that went into this, that is why I am simply saying AV Camera. My problem is, that when I rotate the device, the preview layer is not rotating with the device as well. This is aside having any buttons or recording actions of any kind, simply just the preview of what is to be captured.

I have looked all around here and the internet, but I cannot find anything that can just simply explain to me the steps involved in doing rotating this preview correctly with the device when it is rotated. All of the information that I find is bits and pieces and really hard to try to understand how those code snippets can be modified to my logic.

It would be really nice if I could get a step by step logical basis on where I need to go with rotating this preview layer correctly with my device. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code where you get the layer.

Comment: I had a lot of issues with this and in the end I just went with using a UIImagePickerController, even after finding a workable solution. But I guess it depends on how much customization you need.

Comment: I figured it out and have posted the answer. It was actually not that bad once I just committed to transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out! I just needed to apply the standard transformation rotation matrix that we all learned in linear algebra!. This function rotates the `videoPreviewLayer` with the device rotation after registering for the notification of device rotation in `viewWillAppear`.

Although the rotation is not smooth for this. You can see the edges of the layer as it is rotating with the device. I have tried dispatching it to its own queue, but it doesn't make much of a difference.

My solution to this is going to be locking the preview layer to one orientation, `UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait`, and then apply `deviceOrientationDidChange()` on the buttons I will have in the view. I suspect I will have to apply it to the video/picture data when I press capture too, in order for the user to be able to ultimately view it in the way they took the video/picture. (please, correct me if I am wrong)

```
/**************************************************************************
    DEVICE ORIENTATION DID CHANGE
    **************************************************************************/
    func deviceOrientationDidChange() {

        println("DEVICE ORIENTATION DID CHANGE CALLED")
        let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

        //------ IGNORE THESE ORIENTATIONS ------
        if orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceUp || orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceDown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown || self.currentOrientation == orientation {
            println("device orientation is \(orientation) --- returning...")
            return
        }


        self.currentOrientation = orientation


        //------ APPLY A ROTATION USING THE STANDARD ROTATION TRANSFORMATION MATRIX in R3 ------
        /*

             x     y      z
           ---           ---
        x | cosø  -sinø   0 |
        y | sinø  cosø    0 |
        z | 0     0       1 |
           ---           ---

        BUT IMPLEMENTED BY APPLE AS

            x       y       z
           ---            ---
        x | cosø    sinø    0 |
        y | -sinø   consø   0 |
        z | 0       0       1 |
            ---            ---
        */

        //----- PERFORM VIDEO PREVIEW LAYER ROTATION BEFORE CAMERA CONTROLLER ROTATION ------

        switch orientation {

        case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
            println("Device Orientation Portrait")
            if self.usingFrontCamera == true {
            }
            else {
                self.playBackTransformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.degrees0)
                self.videoPreviewLayer?.setAffineTransform(self.playBackTransformation!)
                self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds
            }
            break
        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            println("Device Orientation LandScapeLeft")
            if self.usingFrontCamera == true {
            }
            else {
                self.playBackTransformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-self.degrees90))
                self.videoPreviewLayer?.setAffineTransform(self.playBackTransformation!)
                self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds
            }
            break
        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            println("Device Orientation LandscapeRight")
            if self.usingFrontCamera == true {
            }
            else {
                self.playBackTransformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.degrees90)
                self.videoPreviewLayer?.setAffineTransform(self.playBackTransformation!)
                self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```